# Why am I getting access violating reading location when I try to set value of shared_ptr<T> element

Tags: class, c++11, shared-ptr

I'm getting access violation reading location when I try to set data of class object.

```
void make_heap_array()
{
    //Example of ptr_arr is define: It's define in class variables: vector<shared_ptr<Data_Node<Item>>> ptr_arr;

    int total_data = arr_data.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < total_data; i++)
    {
        shared_ptr<Data_Node<Item>> new_node = shared_ptr<Data_Node<Item>>();
        Item data = arr_data[i];
        new_node->set_data(data); //Error: Access violation reading location
        ptr_arr.push_back(new_node);

    }
}
```

Data_Node is class using template with few methods and here is it's code:

```
template <class Item>
class Data_Node
{
    Item info; 
public:
    const Item& data() const
    {
        return info;
    }
    void set_data(const Item& new_data)
    {
        info = new_data;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`new_node` is null (as you might well have checked yourself), so `new_node->set_data(data)` has undefined behaviour. (The default-constructed state of a shared pointer is null.)

Comment: Do you know how I can fix that?

Comment: @Gaurav: Fix what? I have no idea what your goal is. Maybe construct a shared pointer that holds an object, e.g. with `make_shared`?

Comment: well, I'm trying to make Data_Node object that is shared_ptr.